# Transfer data from one Mysql table to another with an extra column having a string

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a Mysql table called register and i want to transfer all the details from `register` to `login` table with an extra column which has a password auto generated.

**this is my Servlet where i have autogenerated password:**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String passWord=Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(Math.random()));
        System.out.println(passWord);
        String Id=request.getParameter("id");
        int id=Integer.parseInt(Id);
        AffiliateApproveService approve=new AffiliateApproveService();
        approve.affiliateApprove(id,passWord);

    }
```

Here i have generated an alphanumeric password for column PassWord as a String "passWord" how to assign passWord to PassWord column....

**This is my service class:**

```
public class AffiliateApproveService {

    public void affiliateApprove(int id,String passWord) {
        AffiliateApproveDAO cad=new AffiliateApproveDAO();
        DataSource dataSource=new DataSource();
        cad.setDataSource(dataSource);
        cad.insertClient(id);
        cad.updateClient(id, passWord);
        cad.deleteClient(id);

    }
```

**And this is my DAO:**

```
public class AffiliateApproveDAO {

        private DataSource dataSource;
        public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
       this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
    Connection conn=null;
    PreparedStatement statement=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;


    public void insertClient(int id) {    

        try{

            conn=dataSource.createConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into login(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.executeUpdate("insert into login ( id, FirstName, LastName, Gender, Category, DateOfBirth, Age, Address, Country,  State, city, PinCode, UserName, EmailId, ContactNo, MobileNo)select id, FirstName, LastName, Gender, Category, DateOfBirth, Age, Address, Country,  State, city, PinCode, UserName, EmailId, ContactNo, MobileNo  from  register where id="+id+" ");
            ps.setInt(1, id);

}
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

    } finally {
            if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
        if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
        if (conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
    }


    }


    public void deleteClient(int id) {
        try{
            conn=dataSource.createConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps1=conn.prepareStatement("delete from register where id="+id+"");
            ps1.executeUpdate();
      }
          catch (SQLException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);

      } finally {
              if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
          if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
          if (conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
      }
    }


public void updateClient(int id,String passWord){

    try{
        conn=dataSource.createConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE login set PassWord= "+passWord+" where id="+id+"");
        ps.executeUpdate();
  }
      catch (SQLException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);

  } finally {
          if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
      if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
      if (conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
  }
}


}
```

this is my DDl for Login table

```
create table login(
id int(100) not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
FirstName varchar(300) default null,
LastName varchar(300) default null,
Gender varchar(200) default null,
Category varchar(200) default null,
DateOfBirth varchar(200) default null,
Age int(7)default null,
Address varchar(1000) default null,
Country varchar(500) default null,
State varchar (500) default null,
city varchar(500)default null,
PinCode int(10)default null,
UserName varchar(100)default null,
EmailId varchar(500)default null,
ContactNo varchar(20) default null,
MobileNo varchar(20) default null,
TimeStamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PassWord varchar(100)null default null
);
```

and this is my DDl for register table:

```
create table register(
id int(100) not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
FirstName varchar(300) default null,
LastName varchar(300) default null,
Gender varchar(200) default null,
Category varchar(200) default null,
DateOfBirth varchar(200) default null,
Age int(3)default null,
Address varchar(1000) default null,
Country varchar(500) default null,
State varchar (500) default null,
city varchar(500)default null,
PinCode int(10)default null,
UserName varchar(500)default null,
EmailId varchar(500)default null,
ContactNo varchar(20) default null,
MobileNo varchar(20) default null,
TimeStamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

**Now my Question is in updateClient() method how to update column PassWord in login table with the value of the variable passWord Please help me fix this... Thanks in advance...**

Comment: can you give the details of both `login` table and `register` table?

Comment: -pls find the DDls of both tables

Comment: @user3349720 Can you check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you i solved my question on my own: Thank u for all the help.....

I changed my DAo method updateClient(int id, String Password)as:

```
try{
        conn=dataSource.createConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE login set PassWord= '"+passWord+"'  where id="+id+"");
        ps.executeUpdate();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will help you,

```
"insert into login 
(id, FirtName, LastName, Gender, Category, DateOfBirth, Age, Address, Country, State, city, PinCode, UserName, EmailId, ContactNo, MobileNo, PassWord)
((select * from register where id="+id+" "),password);
```

Comment: - The method executeUpdate(String, int) in the type Statement is not applicable for the arguments (String, 
  String)
 - Syntax error on token ")", delete this token.........Am getting this error

Comment: try with deleting that.

Answer (score 0):

**You must match the column name in both table before inserting**... the create the `login` table as follows.TrChange the column position according to `register` table

```
create table login(
id int(100) not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
FirstName varchar(300) default null,
LastName varchar(300) default null,
Gender varchar(200) default null,
Category varchar(200) default null,
DateOfBirth varchar(200) default null,
Age int(7)default null,
Address varchar(1000) default null,
Country varchar(500) default null,
State varchar (500) default null,
city varchar(500)default null,
PinCode int(10)default null,
UserName varchar(100)default null,
EmailId varchar(500)default null,
ContactNo varchar(20) default null,
MobileNo varchar(20) default null,
TimeStamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PassWord varchar(100)null default null
);
```

---

```
INSERT INTO login
SELECT *, 'passWord' as Password
FROM   register
```

## [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da3eb/1)

[image]

Comment: hey i tried this but value of password is not getting inserted but only string passWord is getting inserted.... I want the value of passWord to be inserted.. cos i have auto generated password

Comment: @user3349720 register table doesnot have column name like PassWord..So you have to insert manually

Comment: Or else try change Password as PassWord varchar(100) not null AUTO_INCREMENT in login table

Comment: @user3349720 Mark this answer as useful If I helped you

Answer (score 0):

You should **match number and name of columns** of `register` table to `login` table while inserting.

Another thing, since your **id field is set to autoincrement** no need to insert into that column

```
insert into login 
(
 FirtName, LastName, Gender, Category, DateOfBirth, Age, Address, Country, 
 State, city, PinCode, UserName, EmailId, ContactNo, MobileNo, PassWord
 )
 select FirtName, LastName, Gender, Category, DateOfBirth, Age, Address, Country, 
   State, city, PinCode, UserName, EmailId, ContactNo, MobileNo, 'PassWord' from 
   register   where id="+id+" ;
```